# Yii Json to Array dropdownlist

Tags: php, json, yii

I have a json like this:

```
{"response":{"count":7,"list":[{"kdTeacher":"001","nmTeacher":"Eulis Irma"},{"kdTeacher":"002","nmTeacher":"Ni Wayan"},{"kdTeacher":"003","nmTeacher":"Dwi Widi"}]},"metaData":{"message":"OK","code":200}}
```

I want the teacher name and the teacher code display in dropdownlist.

In my controller like this:

```
$model=new Teacher;

$paises = file_get_contents(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.assets') .
   DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "teacher.json");
$jsondecode = CJSON::decode($paises, true);

$temp = array();

foreach ($jsondecode as $key => $value) {
        $temp[] = $value;
}

    $this->render('techer', array(
        'data'=>$temp,
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

and in view

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'nama',CHtml::listData($data,'kodeTeacher','nmTeacher')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
</div>
```

id

Comment: If you ask a question, it should be a question and not a tag cloud.

Comment: Please try to improve your spelling. Although high level English is not expected here, but you can get much better acceptance if you follow this [six simple spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you can't get teacher data, because you use wrong data for foreach loop. Teacher code and name are stored at `['response']['list']` index of decoded json. Take a look:

```
$model=new Teacher;

$paises = file_get_contents(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.assets') .
   DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "teacher.json");

$decodedJson = json_decode($paises, true);
$temp = array();

//check if list of teachers is available
if(isset($decodedJson['response']) && isset($decodedJson['response']['list']))
{
    //use foreach on ['response']['list'] index - here are teachers data stored
    foreach($decodedJson['response']['list'] as $teacher)
        $temp[$teacher['kdTeacher']] = $teacher['nmTeacher'];
}

$this->render('techer', array(
    'data'=>$temp,
    'model'=>$model,
));
```

Working example of get teachers data from JSON: [**CLICK!!!**](https://eval.in/569496)

And in view (now you don't need to use `CHtml::listData` method):

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'nama',$data); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
</div>
```